# Storing data about objects with a variable number of ordered subparts in Access Database

Tags: sql, ms-access

The situation: I have a database storing biological specimen data. One table contains data about each specimen. Each specimen has between 1 and 8 parts, which are ordered.

I would like to enumerate each subpart in a query, using the specimen id and the number of parts. So if I have 2 specimens, A and B, and A has 2 parts and B has 3 parts, I want the result:

Parts:

A - 1

A - 2

B - 1

B - 2

B - 3

I realize that this is probably a trivial task, but I don't know the correct terminology to talk about it in a way that help pages and Google will understand. Thank you.

Edit to add thoughts: If I were dealing with something like this in a non-SQL context, I'd use a for loop to iterate the enumeration process over each specimen, but I don't understand how to implement anything remotely similar in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned "main table" which implies there's some other table for the sub parts. What you're after is likely a simple JOIN:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  maintable
  INNER JOIN
  subtable
  ON
    subtable.mainid = maintable.id
```

If you want an exact query, post a screenshot of your database tables and their column names and any relationships

Comment: No, sorry for the confusion. I meant that the main table in my whole database is the specimen table, which I guess is irrelevant and distracting detail. There's no table for subparts; that's what I want to generate here. It's not _that_ trivial a task!